# Xcode shows me all font style names as same in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I added custom font into my ios project.Its name is **Museo**. It has three styles : **Light, Medium** and **Bold**. I added fonts as **UIAppFonts** into .*plist* file to choose them in interface builder. But they seems same name : Regular.

**myapp.plist file**

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Museo100-Light.otf</string>
        <string>Museo300-Medium.otf</string>
        <string>Museo700-Bold.otf</string>
</array>
```

**My font files (Directory):**

```
Fonts
 - Museo100-Light.otf
 - Museo300-Medium.otf
 - Museo700-Bold.otf
```

**Note:** I changed font files's names. Their names end with *Regular*. Is this problem related with this situation? If it is, does xcode cache font file names?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Force Quit your Xcode and then try... it might work.

Comment: This happened to me once too...installing the font on the computer (not just in Xcode) fixed it for me.

Comment: Yeaaaaah. Thank you very much. You saved me :)))

Comment: Awesome! :) I will make than an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you double-click on the font file, it should open with the option to "Install Font" in the lower-right. Install it to your computer, and it should help Xcode tell the difference.